# Loop MySQL Dynamic SQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a mysql stored procedure can loop and fetch dynamic sql without using a cursor.

Let Say I Have

```
SET @SQLSTATEMENT = CONCAT('SELECT FLD1,FLD2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE FLD1 = \'',PARAM1,'\';');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLSTATEMENT;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Without using cursor i want to get the results of that statement, loop through and create another select statement inside it.

The Idea is something like

```
Execute SQLStatement
Get Result

Loop
    fetch columns
    execute another sql statement
    get result
    loop
       fetch columns
       fire insert statement
    end loop
End Loop
```

To do this i need to create two or more procedure with cursor. Is there any way to do this in one procedure only?

Please Help. Thank you

Comment: Why are you not using a cursor?

Comment: Hi @EdHeal, i am just newby in mysql stored procedure, and if i am right cursor must be declared before any set or line. In this case we'll be needing two cursors

Comment: Is the exercise about learning about sprocs or about completing a specific task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this way

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ProcSample`(
In Parameter1  VARCHAR(4),
In Parameter2 VARCHAR(2),
In Parameter3 VARCHAR(2),
In Paremeter4 VARCHAR(2)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT(11);
DECLARE j INT(11);
DECLARE SCHEMACOUNT INT(11);
DECLARE TABLENAME VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE RECORDCOUNT INT(11);


Delete from  `sampledb`.`sampletable`;

SET @SCHEMACOUNT = 0;
SET @SQLSTATEMENT = CONCAT('
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(TABLE_NAME) INTO @SCHEMACOUNT FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE \'%String%\' AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT LIKE \'%String%\'
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE \'%String%',Parameter1,Parameter2,'%\';'
);
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLSTATEMENT;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


SET @TABLENAME = '';
SET @i = 0;
WHILE @i < @SCHEMACOUNT DO

    SET @SQLSTATEMENT = CONCAT('
        SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,\'.\',TABLE_NAME) INTO @TABLENAME FROM information_schema.`TABLES`
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE \'%String%\' AND TABLE_SCHEMA NOT LIKE \'%String%\'
        AND TABLE_NAME LIKE \'%String%',Parameter1,Parameter2,'%\'
        ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME 
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET ',@i
    );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLSTATEMENT;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET @RECORDCOUNT = 0;
    SET @SQLSTATEMENT = CONCAT('
        SELECT  DISTINCT COUNT(`IndexKey`) INTO @RECORDCOUNT FROM ',@TABLENAME,' 
        WHERE `Field1` = \'Value1\' and `Field2` = \'Value2\` '
    );


    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLSTATEMENT;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET @j = 0 ;
    WHILE @j < @RECORDCOUNT DO
        SET @SQLSTATEMENT = CONCAT('
            INSERT INTO `sampledb`.`sampletable` 
            (`Field1`,`Field2`,`Field3`)
            SELECT  `Field1`,`Field2`,`Field3` FROM ',@TABLENAME,' 
            WHERE `Field1` = \'Value1\' and `Field2` = \'Value2\` 
            LIMIT 1 OFFSET ',@j,';'
        );

        PREPARE stmt FROM @SQLSTATEMENT;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


        SET @j = @j + 1;
    END WHILE;


    SET @i = @i + 1;
END WHILE;



END
```

Comment: It may seem a little nasty, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Also, I suggest you to chage the statement that counting rows from the `information.schema`, to use `FOUND_ROWS()`. It will be : `SET @SCHEMACOUNT = FOUND_ROWS();`.